# NSDate extension of compare two NSDates is throws warning

Tags: ios, swift

My core data entity has an attribute of NSDate class, as

```
@NSManaged public var journalDateTime: NSDate?
```

I want to compare and sort my records by NSDates with compare function of NSDate extension as

```
open func compare(_ other: Date) -> ComparisonResult
```

I wrote my code as

```
if modificateionDate.compare(latestJournal?.journalDateTime! as! Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
     beerObject?.beerIndex?.modificationDate = latestJournal?.journalDateTime as NSDate?
}
```

Which is showing my warning like attached image, I have gone through Date and NSDate class for this warning but did not find any solution.[image]

Please let me know if you have any single line solution for this warning. For now, I'm just ignoring this warning.

Thanks.

Comment: The warning contains the solution. Also Xcode already asks you if it should automatically fix it. So what is the question?

Comment: In Swift 3 declare the `@NSManaged` property as `Date` and you can compare dates with the `>` operator. And there are too many question and exclamation marks, consider to declare the date property as non-optional.

Comment: Auto fixes are not working... its goes to infinite correction loop

Answer (score 0):

the warning is practically meaningless, atleast for now (current swift, ios, Xcode version) but just to be on the safe side, try to change your model to use Date instead of NSDate in the first place , that way you wont even have to cast the object and there will be no warning.
here is what Apple has to say about this topic:

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the Date structure, which bridges to the NSDate class. The Date value type offers the same functionality as the NSDate reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges standard string, numeric, and collection types to their corresponding Foundation classes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Digging for this Date and NSDate in depth. (y)

Answer (score 0):

The warning is basically saying that you can do the same thing in a more concise way, basically by unwrapping your optional first, and then just bridge between the two types with `as`.

The safer way to do the comparison is this:

```
if let journalDateTime = latestJournal?.journalDateTime as? Date {
    if modificateionDate > journalDateTime {
        // your code
    }
}
```

If you have to use your custom `compare` method, then use the code below:

```
if let journalDateTime = latestJournal?.journalDateTime as? Date {
    if modificateionDate.compare(journalDateTime) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
        beerObject?.beerIndex?.modificationDate = journalDateTime as NSDate
    }
}
```

P.S. you can use the comparison operators with `Date` in Swift.

Comment: And could also result in crashes if the optional is set to nil. Force unwrapping is more often than not a bad practice. You should safely unwrap optional unless you are 100% sure that optional actually has a value.

Comment: Of course it can, but he/she is practically doing the same thing with `as!`. I can only assume OP is certain that the optional has a value at that moment.

Comment: compare is the extension in NSDate which returns -> ComparisonResult, But the thing is I have Two NSDate and in parameter its expected Date instead of NSdate.

Comment: @AshwinIndianic If you are satisfied you can accept the answer :). If not, let me know.

Comment: @TGO, Actually my concern is about "compare" function. I can remove the warning, But I want to know can we convert NSDate class to Date structure directly?

Comment: @AshwinIndianic Yes you can convert an NSDate object to a Date object, if that's what you're asking.